# Run process through java program

Tags: java, linux, process, system-calls

I am working in java for Ubuntu environment. I want to execute a script file but through java program. I have tried followings

```
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/lib/flume-ng/bin/flume-ng agent -f /home/c4/Flume/New/ClientAgent.config -n clientAgent");
}
catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/lib/flume-ng/bin/flume-ng", "agent", 
               "-f", "/home/c4/Flume/New/ClientAgent.config","-n","clientAgent");
            try{
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

But both of these don't start my process named: flume-ng, other are parameters passed to it. Java program compiles successfully but neither gives exception etc nor run process. Please guide me if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Pehrpas your program is returning an error code which you are ignoring (check for pb.waitFor()) or it is returning an error message which you are also discarding. pb.getErrorStream().

Comment: You need to handle standard input and output of the newly spawned process. I would consider using Apache Commons Exec like Rafael suggested :)

Comment: I got no error (compile time or run time). But process is not executed

Comment: first, try catching throwable (temporarily). second, run this hjava app under strace and see what that logs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)

It provides reliable and cross-platform mechanism to launch external processes.

Here is the latest javadoc: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/index.html

And here is the simple tutorial: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html